# glance is not getting installed with depedencies on ubuntu

Tags: openstack-glance, glance

```
apt install -y glance
```

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
>   information... Done glance is already the newest version
>   (2:19.0.2-0ubuntu1~cloud0). You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken
>   install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies:  python3-glance-store : Depends: python3-cinderclient
>   (>= 1:3.3.0) but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet
>   dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or
>   specify a solution).

when I try to install python3-cinderclient.

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>   dkms efibootmgr gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 libfwup1 libllvm8 libwayland-egl1-mesa ubuntu-web-launchers
> Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   python3-cinderclient
> 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
> 40 not fully installed or removed.
> Need to get 0 B/136 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 1,129 kB of additional disk space will be used.
> (Reading database ... 196495 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack .../python3-cinderclient_1%3a5.0.0-0ubuntu2~cloud0_all.deb ...
> Unpacking python3-cinderclient (1:5.0.0-0ubuntu2~cloud0) ...
> dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-cinderclient_1%3a5.0.0-0ubuntu2~cloud0_all.deb
> ```
>
> (--unpack):
>        trying to overwrite '/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/cinder.bash_completion', which
>   is also in package python-cinderclient 1:3.5.0-0ubuntu1
>       Errors were encountered while processing:
>        /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-cinderclient_1%3a5.0.0-0ubuntu2~cloud0_all.deb
>       E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

If I ignore this and ran any glance image upload, I am getting this error.

openstack:

```
openstack image create cirros3.5 --file cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.img --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --public
```

> Error finding address for http://controller:9292/v2/schemas/image:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=9292): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /v2/schemas/image (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused',)) root@controller:/home/osboxes# openstack image
>   create cirros3.5 --file cirros-0.3.5-x86_64-disk.img --disk-format
>   qcow2 --container-format bare --public

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

I used the below command to force overwrite the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite \
  /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-cinderclient_1%3a5.0.0-0ubuntu2~cloud0_all.deb
```

Please let me know if this solves your problem